# Excel VBA XIRR not working as expected

Tags: vba, excel

I am working a code, and I have a problem with Excel's `XIRR` function.

You have a matrix with 2 columns (dates and amounts), so the inputs are the matrix, a date, and a quantity. Inside the code it takes the values below the date you used as input, makes a new array with those values, and add also the date and amount you entered as inputs. And the output should be the `XIRR` of that array. It doesn´t seem to work. It works with `IRR`, with dates are an important input. Does someone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
Function Retorno(matriz As Range, dia As Date, valuacion As Double) As Double
Dim Datos As Range
Dim Aux1()
Dim Aux2()
Dim i, j, m, n As Integer

Set Datos = matriz
j = 0
For i = 1 To Datos.Rows.Count
    If Datos(i, 1) <= dia Then
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

ReDim Aux1(1 To j + 1)
ReDim Aux2(1 To j + 1)

For n = 1 To j + 1
    Aux1(n) = Datos(n, 2)
Next n

Aux1(j + 1) = valuacion

For m = 1 To j + 1
    Aux2(m) = Datos(m, 1)
Next m

Aux2(j + 1) = dia

Retorno = WorksheetFunction.Xirr(Aux1, Aux2)
End Function
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What does "Doesn't seem to work" mean though. Is it erroring? Is the `retorno` holding an incorrect value? something else?

Comment: Please explain "*doesn't seem to work*".  Error message?  Wrong answer?  Excel crashes?  Also, to make it easier to help you, please edit your question to show an example of your data (in a text format that can be easily copy/pasted) along with your actual and desired outputs.  To post it as text, perhaps this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) would be useful

Comment: It shows #VALUE!

For example

Matrix
27/06/2013 -$816,300,000.00
30/11/2015 -$179,025,060.00
dia: 30/12/2015
valuacion: $747,586,979
expected answer: -13.29%

Answer (score 0):

Your last `Aux2(j + 1) = dia` is overwriting the second date in the array with the first date, giving you two identical dates in the date array.

Possibly you want to delete that line.

Comment: I tried to delete the line but the error was still there. I am sure it has to do something with Aux2 because it works well with IRR function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the line deleted and my entering made-up input.  Since the data you are using you only posted in a comment, making it hard to tell how it is laid out, and since you did not post the formula, actual inputs and desired output, I can't advise further at this time.  If you choose to provide that data, I'll take another look.

Comment: Thank you I resolved the problem. It appears that Xirr inside vba takes date format  as "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of the one i am used to and was used as input "dd/mm/yyyy". So i have to change the format and everthing goes as it is suppose to.

Comment: @JoséMurguía I'm glad you've got it working, and surprised that formatting makes a difference.  Instead of fiddling with the format, what happens if you populate the dates using the `.Value2` property?  eg:  `Aux2(m) = Datos(m, 1).Value2`

Answer (score 0):

The other possible answer to this problem is to convert the date to numbers if you do this: Aux2(m) = Datos(m, 1)*1 XIRR will work too.